# Validation for Drop Down Selection

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, validation

I have drop down lists in every cell in each column. If i select say GR1 for batch code BOL under process 1 i can use GR1 for that batch code but not for any other batch code.

As soon as i select GR1 anywhere else in any other process for any other batch code except BOL i should get an error stating i cannot select it.

Also just to make it clear the values in the dropdown have been populated based on a condition from an array.

Currently i can select the same value throughout the sheet.

[image]

PLEASE FIND THE CODE USED TO GENERATE THE VALUES IN THE DROP DOWNS

```
Option Explicit

Sub try()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim st, gr, bl, rc, co, ec, ct As Object

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P").Range("E2:K150").Clear

For i = 2 To 160

Set st = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set gr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set bl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set rc = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set co = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set ec = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set ct = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For j = 5 To 160

If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("P").Cells(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(j, 1)) Then

For k = 6 To 160

If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(j, k) <> "") Then

For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(1, k)

Select Case c.Value

Case "S"
st.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "G"
gr.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "B"
bl.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "R"
rc.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "C"
co.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "E"
ec.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value
Case "Co"
ct.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("M").Cells(3, k).Value

End Select

Next c

End If

Next k

End If

Next j

Range("P!E" & i).Clear
Range("P!F" & i).Clear
Range("P!G" & i).Clear
Range("P!H" & i).Clear
Range("P!I" & i).Clear
Range("P!J" & i).Clear
Range("P!K" & i).Clear

If (st.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!E" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(st.toarray, ",")

End If

If (gr.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!F" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(gr.toarray, ",")

End If

If (bl.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!G" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(bl.toarray, ",")

End If

If (rc.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!H" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(rc.toarray, ",")

End If

If (co.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!I" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(co.toarray, ",")

End If

If (ec.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!J" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(ec.toarray, ",")

End If

If (ct.Count <> 0) Then

Range("P!K" & i).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(ct.toarray, ",")

End If

Set st = Nothing
Set gr = Nothing
Set bl = Nothing
Set rc = Nothing
Set co = Nothing
Set ec = Nothing
Set ct = Nothing

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the board Rish.  Could you reword that please?  I've read the question five or six times and don't understand it.  It sounds like you don't want to be able to select the same item for a process, but not sure.

Comment: Hi  Darren Bartrup-Cook, I have edited the question. Can you let me know if its clear now.

Comment: By default, Excel allows you to select whatever you want. Since you seem to have code to set Data Validation that same code should be responsible for any restraints placed on that freedom. Please publish your code. However, let me say that I have avoided a lot of DV dropdowns when faced with similar tasks. Setting DV is a very short and simple code which can be called by a `Selection_Change` event procedure. The DV set for the previously selected cell is always removed. Therefore you never have more than one DV on the sheet. Hence the DVs can't interfere with each other.

Comment: Please find the code used to generate the drop downs

Comment: In VBA, each variable must be declared individually. They do not inherit the type of the last item on the line.  I suggest changing `Dim st, gr, bl, rc, co, ec, ct As Object` to `Dim st as object, gr as object, bl as object,,,,`  As written, onlt `ct` is an `Object`, the rest are `Variant`

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

**Edit:**

*Retain validation criteria if in same row as selected cell*

Use a `Worksheet_SelectionChange`  event to modify the Validation list on-the-fly.

For example:

The code below is entered as worksheet code for the range where you have the data validation.

It assumes you have already set this up as you describe in your question.

```
'myList and myRange are assumed to be named ranges in your workbook referring
'to the full Validation List and the Range over which the
'Validation is to be applied.
'
'You can refer to them by other means, depending on your setup
'
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim col As Collection
  Dim V, W, X, I As Long

On Error GoTo Err

If Selection.Count > 1 Then Set Target = Selection(1, 1)
Target.Select

If Not Intersect(Target, [myrange]) Is Nothing Then
    Set col = New Collection
    With [myrange]
        For Each V In [mylist] 'or however the validation list is set up
            If .Find(what:=V, after:=.Item(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
                    col.Add V, V
            End If
        Next V

        'Add contents of any cell in same row as target
        For Each W In Intersect([myrange], Target.EntireRow).Cells
            If Len(W.Value) > 0 Then
                For Each V In [mylist]
                    If V = W.Value Then col.Add W, W
                Next V
            End If
        Next W
    End With

    ReDim W(1 To col.Count)
    I = 0
    For Each V In col
        I = I + 1
        W(I) = V
    Next V

    customSort W, [mylist]

'Can either modify the pre-existing validation or,
' may be safer to just set up a new validation on-the-fly

'Target.Validation.Modify Formula1:=Join(W, ",")

' may be safer to just set up a new validation on-the-fly

'Set up new validation
With Target.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=Join(W, ",")
End With

End If
Exit Sub

Err:
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 457 'don't add duplicate strings
        Resume Next
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error number: " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
End Select

End Sub

'Maintain dropdown in same order as original list
Sub customSort(arrToSort, arrOrder)
  Dim col As Collection
  Dim V, W, I As Long

Set col = New Collection
For Each W In arrOrder
    For Each V In arrToSort
        If V = W Then
            col.Add V
        End If
    Next V
Next W

I = LBound(arrToSort)
For Each V In col
    arrToSort(I) = V
    I = I + 1
Next V

End Sub
```

Comment: hi Ron i only want to make sure the user cannot select the same value or is made aware its already selected somewhere else.

Comment: another thing is the above code will remove the previous validation which will remove the values generated for the drop down. those values are not stored anywhere but are generated based on a criteria

Comment: @Rish With a validation that excludes the disallowed entries, they won't be able to enter them. And you should be able to write a routine that regenerates your list. You could write event code that pops up a warning if the selection is bad, but all of the entries would still be in the list.That seems less desirable to me.

Comment: regenerating the list will be running the my code again which will not only regenerate the list for the desired cell but will follow the procedure for the entire sheet.

Comment: @Rish If it is the "list" problem that is keeping you from using this method, I suggest storing the list after you generate it so that it remains available to the macro until it changes, perhaps as a **named constant**.

Comment: @Rish Looking quickly at your code, if you have multiple areas with different validation lists, I would rewrite the macro above to use `[myRange]` and `[myList]` as input variables;  then use the `SelectionChange` to determine which area you are in and which validation list to use and input those to the rewritten macro.

Answer (score -1):

I found the code I referred to in my above comment and sterilized it. The first part goes into the worksheet's code module.

```
Option Explicit

    Dim PrevCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' 26 Mar 2015
    SetFilter Account
    Set PrevCell = Cells(1, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 24 Apr 2015

    Dim Clm() As Variant
    Dim Lid() As Variant
    Dim GotVal As Boolean
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' setting the columns in which to set validation
    Set Rng = Application.Union(AccRange(2), _
                                AccRange(4), _
                                AccRange(5), _
                                AccRange(8))
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo NoPrevCell

    ' delete existing validation in the previously selected cell
    If Insect(PrevCell, Rng) = False Then SetValidation PrevCell, Del:=True

    GetProps Target, R, C
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
        SetValidation Target, 3, 1
    End If

    Set PrevCell = Target

SideExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

NoPrevCell:
    Set PrevCell = Cells(1, 1)
    Resume 0
End Sub
```

Below are supporting procedures required to run the code. I have left more code there than would obviously be required, for two reasons. One, it would take time to remove it. Two, you might use some of the approaches I used five years ago.

```
Function AccRange(Optional C As Long, _
              Optional Rl As Long, _
              Optional Ct As Long = 3) As Range
' 23 Mar 2015
' Return only column C, if specified
' Use column Ct to determine the last row, if Rl isn't specified

Ct = WorksheetFunction.Max(Ct, 1)
With Worksheets("Account")
    If Rl = 0 Then Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Ct).End(xlUpt).Row
    Set AccRange = .Range(.Cells(2, C), .Cells(Rl, C))
End With
```

End Function

Function GetProps(Target As Range, _
                  Optional R As Long, _
                  Optional C As Long, _
                  Optional V As Variant, _
                  Optional Ws As Worksheet)
    ' 22 May 2015

```
With Target
    R = .Row
    C = .Column
    V = .Value
    Set Ws = .Worksheet
End With
```

End Function

Sub SetValidation(Tgt As Range, _
                  Optional Lid As Nnr, _
                  Optional Lclm As Long, _
                  Optional SelectOnly As Boolean, _
                  Optional Del As Boolean)
    ' 07 Apr 2015
    ' Set or delete validation in Tgt

```
' Tgt is a cell requiring validation
' Lid identifies a named range containing a list
' Lclm identifies a column within that named range
' SelectOnly sets Error behaviour
' If Del = True the existing validation is deleted
'   without setting a new one.

Dim Lv As String

With Tgt.Validation
    .Delete

    If Not Del Then
        Lv = GetListValues(Lid, Lclm)
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Lv
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .ShowError = SelectOnly
        If SelectOnly Then
            .ErrorTitle = "Required entry"
            .ErrorMessage = "Please select an existing list item."
        End If
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Private Function GetListValues(Lid As Nnr, _
                               Lclm As Long) As String
    ' 07 Apr 2015

```
' Lid identifies a named range containing a list
' Lclm identifies a column within that named range

Dim Fun As String                       ' Function return value
Dim Itm As String                       ' List Item
Dim i As Long

Lclm = WorksheetFunction.Max(Lclm, 1)

With ListRange(Lid).Columns(Lclm)       ' returns the list
    For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
        Itm = Trim(.Cells(i).Value)
        If Len(Itm) Then
            Fun = Fun & .Cells(i).Value & Sep
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If (Lid = 3) And (Lclm = 1) And _
       (CountA(ListRange(3).Columns(1)) > 0) Then
       ' add an item to the list under special circumstances
        Fun = Fun & "Special item" & Sep
    End If
End With

GetListValues = Left(Fun, Len(Fun) - 1)
```

End Function

Function Sep() As String
    ' 22 Feb 2015

```
Sep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
```

End Function

Sorry, SO didn't allow me to post the format my original code has.